# Java Read Line of Integers from console

Tags: java

What I need to do is that I have a series of lines of integers and have to read them from console.  I have adopted the following method. I read a line and then split it using the delimiter as space, collect the integers into a string array and then typecast each of the element of the string array. I find this method very cumbersome. Is there any other simpler method to achieve the same in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(theLine);
while (in.hasNextInt())
    add in.nextInt() to arraylist or something
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using something like java.io.Scanner, and its methods for grabbing variables of various types.